# Suppress millions of "Refreshing state..." lines in terraform / terragrunt plan output

Tags: terraform, terragrunt

I am invoking `terraform` using `terragrunt`. I have a multitude of resources in my state file, so on each plan I see the extremely noisy output of millions of lines in the likes of

```
random_string.my_resource_a: Refreshing state... [id=none]
random_string.my_resource_b: Refreshing state... [id=none]
random_string.my_resource_c: Refreshing state... [id=none]
random_string.my_resource_d: Refreshing state... [id=none]
.
.
.
.
```

Is there a way to suppress these (except `grep -v`) using either a `terraform` or a `terragrunt` setting?